# Finding expected value per raffle ticket choice

Tags: self-study, distributions, expected-value

> Let's say, that you're entering a raffle. You can choose the amount you will win and will get according amount of tickets.
>
> [image: 1]
>
> N people have entered this raffle. Let's say that there are more participants that chose middle options than participants who chose  extreme options(so the most picked option is \$30, with the least picked options being \$5 and \$60).
>
> How can I find expected value of each choice?

**Source:** I just saw this raffle and wondered what expected values would be.

**My attempts so far:** I googled normal and standard normal distributions, but I don't understand how I could apply it here. The main problem I'm having is counting amount of people who is expected to make each choice, so I can estimate overall amount of tickets. Then I would just multiply prize amount by win probability(my tickets divided by all tickets) to get expected value.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @gung, is my explanation enough? Sorry that I didn't read rules beforehand. I'll delete if you think that this question is too vague and it would take too much time to explain the answer to someone without base knowledge like me.

Comment: That's fine, @ahiskali. You are welcome to ask questions like this here, we just have a set of special policies for them.

Comment: I have no idea why this is being voted to close. It has the `[self-study]` tag, & the OP explains what he has tried thus far. This meets our policies & is on topic here.